# Install multiple versions of a package

Tags: linux, installation

I want to install multiple versions of a package (say libX) from src. The package (libX) uses Autotools to build, so follows the ./configure , make, make install convention. The one installed by default goes to /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/lib and I want to install another version of this in /home/user/libX .

The other problem is that libX is a dependency for another package (say libY) which also uses autotools. How to I make libY point to the version installed in /home/user/libX ? There could be also a possibility that its a system package like ffmpeg and I want to use the latest svn version for my src code and hence build it from src. What do i do in that case ? What is the best practice in this case so that I do not break the system libraries?

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 and Opensuse 10.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can usually pass the `--prefix` option to configure to tell it to install the library in a different place.  So for a personal version, you can usually run it as:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/usr/libX
```

and it will install in `$HOME/usr/libX/bin`, `$HOME/usr/libX/lib`, `$HOME/usr/libX/etc` and so on.

If you are building libY from source, the configure script usually uses the `pkg-config` tool to find out where a package is stored. libX should have included a .pc file in the directory `$HOME/usr/libX/lib/pkgconfig` which tells configure where to look for headers and library files.  You will need to tell the pkg-config tool to look in your directory first.

This is done by setting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH to include your directory first.
When configuring libY, try

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$HOME/usr/libX/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig ./configure
```

`man pkg-config` should give details.